# Insert Flash Version into User-Agent

Tags: javascript, java, user-agent

I have a `Spring Boot` application and what I basically want to do is, upon authentication, log the OS, Browser Version and Flash Version.

So the simple approach that I wanted to do is:

1. Get the `User-Agent` from the request
2. Parse the `User-Agent` using one of the many libraries
3. Log the result of the parsing

But the `User-Agent` doesn't provide the Flash version details. I assume that some sort intervention should be performed client side. The front-end is with `AngularJS`.

Any idea how we can do this?